# Internal and External SD card paths on Optimus 2X

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, lg-optimus-2x, internal-sd

When running the stock Optimus 2X ROM my "internal" SDCARD was mounted at /mnt/sdcard and my external SDCARD was mounted at /mnt/sdcard/_ExternalSD

I have now installed CM7.2 and the "internal" card is now mounted at /mnt/emmc and the external SD card is mounted at /mnt/sdcard

As a result, my restored apps (via Titanium) are looking at /mnt/sdcard for files that are at /mnt/emmc

My questions:

1) why do the two ROMs treat the cards so differently?
2) the stock LG way seems "better" as the "internal" card was actually being used by apps, now it's tucked away at /mnt/emmc how will it be used?
3) what's the ideal way to resolve my "apps looking in the wrong place" problem?
a) just copy the files from /mnt/emmc to /mnt/sdcard?
b) something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small bug in cyanogenmod. You can mount `/emmc` to `/sdcard/external_sd` by folowing command:

```
 su
 mount -o bind /mnt/emmc /sdcard/external_sd
```

You need to install a terminal emulator (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)) in your mobile for excuting command. It's 100% working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple guide, howto fix the emmc Bug on Cyanogenmod.

1.At first install Rom Toolbox.

2.Open Rom Toolbox and scroll Down to Scripter and open it.

3.Click on add and make a script named "Emmc bug"

4.Put " busybox mount /mnt/emmc /mnt/sdcard/external_sd."into the Command field and save.

5.Press on the created script and check run on Boot.

6.Reboot

**Also you can look at [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1545801) post(useful)**